# How to retrieve environment variable by variable in `Powershell`?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, indirection

I have name of my environment variable in `Powershell` script:

```
$credEnvName = "Confluence_Data"
```

How can i retrieve the environment value by this variable?

I tryied this:

```
$value = ${env:$credEnvName}
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-Content` to retrieve its value:

```
$env:Confluence_Data = 'hello world'
$credEnvName = 'Confluence_Data'
Get-Content -Path env:$credEnvName # hello world
```

`Get-Item` expanding on the `.Value` property is another option:

```
(Get-Item env:$credEnvName).Value
```